# information about internet connection in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, internet, connection

I use Ubuntu 11.10.i surf the Internet using GPRS connection with my cell phone as modem.
how do i get to know the speed at which the Internet is running?
I tried clicking on 'connection information' but it says `'connection speed unknown'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) they will measure your speed and Ping.

You can also go to the system monitor and click in the network area. Here you will see what you currently download / upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'System Load Indicator', which works well in **11.10**.

[10 Useful Application Indicators for Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/10-useful-application-indicators-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

KPPP dialer software by Kde.org. claims it gives connection speed readings, Account information among others. Although primarily meant for ethernet connection, it claims to work well for wireless network too. The archieved file is 66mb. May download and give it a try!